# How to read a specific named range from an xlsb excel file using python?

Tags: python, dataframe, named-ranges, xlsb

I am trying to read a specific named range to a dataframe in python. My excel file is in xlsb format.

I have tried to look for it online and it seems like doing this on xlsx format is possible but haven't found anything for xlsb format.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `open_workbook` from `pyxlsb` to process a xlsb file.

Here's a sample code to start with:

```
from pyxlsb import open_workbook
with open_workbook('sample_data.xlsb') as wb:
    # Do stuff with wb
    # Using the sheet index (1-based)
    with wb.get_sheet(1) as sheet:
        for row in sheet.rows():
            print(row)

    # Using the sheet name
    with wb.get_sheet('Sheet1') as sheet:
        # Do stuff with sheet
```

Reference: https://pypi.org/project/pyxlsb/